# Alternatives to converting Domain Model to DTO when passing thru WCF

Tags: wcf, domain-driven-design

I've created a rich domain model that's populate from the UI, and now I need to pass it through WCF to be processed. I need to convert my rich domain model to a DTO to pass through WCF, and I'm going to need it converted back to my rich domain model so I can work with it again.

What are my options here? I just finished created the domain model => DTO conversion, and I feel like it's going to be a pain point to maintain in the future.

Is this where a product like AutoMapper excels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd absolutely recommend AutoMapper as being the tool of choice here.

Here's a great tutorial [by Jimmy Bogard on dnrTV](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=155)

Comment: On first glance, it looks great for flattening my object. But what about from DTO back to domain model?

Comment: I don't know your domain model so I can't tell. But in many cases Automapper can save alot of work in both directions.

Comment: I've reviewed this and some other articles about unflattening, and I don't think I'll need it in this case. If I did, I'd look into ValueInjector.